# Double Video Length With FFMPEG (No Audio)

Tags: ffmpeg, video, fps

I have a time lapse video with 29.97003 FPS. There is no audio. The video is too fast. I would like to lengthen it from 10 seconds to 20 seconds, while keeping each frame with like 15 FPS.

How can I do that with FFMPEG?

It is short and small in file size. Can be reencoded, I don't care. I'm thinking, if there is no quick solution, I could extract frames to JPG files and encode a new video with different FPS. I'm trying to avoid that.

Edit: I tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45465730/1442225

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf \"setpts=2*PTS\" -r 15 -codec:v h264 output.mp4
```

It looks like it did the right thing. output.mp4 has doubled length but same amount of frames. Only the file size shrank to less than 25% of original. I used the same vcodec. I do expect the file size stay almost the same.

Comment: For getting the same file size, try the "Without re-encoding" solution from the link you have posted.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to take out the raw video data from the mp4 container, then you need to put it into a new container and set the new fps value at the same time.

So first: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v copy -f h264 input.h264`

And then: `ffmpeg -r 15 -i input.h264 -c:v copy output.mp4`

Note: As long as you do not use `-c:v copy` (in your edit you used `-codec:v h264` which is the same as `-c:v h264`) FFmpeg will **always** re-encode the input so the output will have some different size.